# Lightning by HDRI is wrong

Tags: lighting, hdri

Scene was made with Daz3D, but I'm sure that lightning will work the same way in any 3D-rendering program.

1-st render is made with all the meshes:

[image: 1-st render]
[image: 2-nd render]
2-nd render was made only with object on the floor and HDRI background of the same room(spherical camera setting was used to render seven frames with different exposures and glue it together into HDRI-image with Photoshop. I used 7 exposure values: 1/15,30,50,125,250,500,1000)

As you can see there is something wrong with lighting(object on the floor is lighted very differently)
I'm looking for the cause of this issue, but lacking experience in HDRI-lightning.

P.S. Another angle in the same scene and all objects are present:
[image: Another angle in the same scene and all objects are present]

Another angle in the same scene with only HDRI background and prop on the floor is used as mesh:
[image: Another angle in the same scene with only HDRI background and prop on the floor is used as mesh]

Comment: Looks to me like the image you are using as environment is not using scene referred values, but has been transformed to display referred ones. I would not trust photoshop to do an HDR image correctly, but I don't use that app anyway. Please describe what format you are using to export the images used to create your "HDRI" A tonemaped image is not the same as a high dynamic range image. If you create the image using OpenEXR instead of other formats for your environment image you will preserve your data as linear scene referred.

Comment: Thank You for the answer

Comment: Image format I was using is "File Type: Radiance (*.HDR;*.RGBE;*.XYZE)